# OpenLayers 3: Geometric filters in method WFS GetFeature

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver, gml

OpenLayers 2 could generate geometric filter method WFS GetFeature.

Example JS:

```
var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({ type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.INTERSECTS, value: geometry, projection: "EPSG:3067" });

var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0();
var filterAsXml = parser.write(filter);
var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
var filterAsString = xml.write( filterAsXml );
```

Example XML:

```
<wfs:GetFeature
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  service="WFS"
  version="1.1.0"
  outputFormat="json"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
  http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<wfs:Query typeName="LiVi:LIIKENNE_ELEMENTTI" srsName="EPSG:3067" xmlns:LiVi="http://site.ru/">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:PropertyName>GEOMETRY</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3067">
          <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
              <gml:posList>308082.07106781186 6833724.928932188 308082.07106781186 6833739.071067812 308067.92893218814 6833739.071067812 308067.92893218814 6833724.928932188 308082.07106781186 6833724.928932188</gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
          </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
      </ogc:Intersects>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

They have a not working [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.ogc.filter.html):

> ```
> var f = ol.format.wfs.filter;
> var request = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
>     srsName: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
>     featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/topp',
>     featurePrefix: 'topp',
>     featureTypes: ['states'],
>     filter: f.and(
>       f.bbox('the_geom', [1, 2, 3, 4], 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326'),
>       f.like('name', 'New*')
>     )
> });
> ```

Either he recently appeared... Judging by the projection - a blank for WFS 2.0.0.

How do I write a geometric filter in the OL3?

***PS2***
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the OpenLayers documentation, which will be fixed with https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5653.

To make the example work, change `ol.format.wfs.filter` to `ol.format.ogc.filter`:

```
var f = ol.format.ogc.filter;
var request = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
    featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/topp',
    featurePrefix: 'topp',
    featureTypes: ['states'],
    filter: f.and(
      f.bbox('the_geom', [1, 2, 3, 4], 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326'),
      f.like('name', 'New*')
    )
});
```

However, the only geometry-like filter OpenLayers supports is BBOX. Other geometry filters, like the one in your WFS XML above, are not supported by OpenLayers 3. If you need full OGC filter support, you may want to have a look at https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas, which provides (among others) OGC filter bindings for [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).